# split a array element by comma delimited string into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

```
$data[10] = "12.21661,13.00128";
$loc = explode(",",$data[10]);
$lat = $loc[0];
$long = $loc[1]; **// Undefined offset:1**
```

When i run above code I got error on `$long = $loc[1];` line ***(Undefined offset:1)***.
How can I resolve this??

Comment: The code works fine, try `print_r($loc);` tell us what is the output.

Comment: Can you post all of the code because I suspect this is just a small piece and I'm guessing that this processing is occuring in a loop

Comment: array
(
    [0] => 12.21661
    [1] => 13.00128
)

Comment: @JanardhanRam share the full code please, offset 0 and 1 both are defined. so thats mean the problem not in code you've shared with us.

Comment: I found solution. My code working fine.

Comment: please enlighten us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in string is 2 digits and 5 decimals. if the number have fixed limits then there is function in PHP : str_split()

Here's documentation , Look at an example , it will be much clear.
it will split in exact length like

Check example : **Example #1 Example uses of str_split()** in documentation 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

or

there is explode() function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

does exactly what you want , I guess.

check out , examples are quite simple.

Any query comment back.